# Visualization with Dart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dart, visualization

My work involves pretty heavy visualization. I have been using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) and [JavaScript Infovis toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) for it.

I recently learned about how Dart is the new way of developing web apps.

Q1. Does Dart provide any libraries for doing visualization (Something of the level of [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) or [JavaScript Infovis toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/)) ?

Q2. If I move on to Dart, will I be able to use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) / [Javascript Infovis toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) along with Dart ?

---

Edit:

I found over the internet that [we can use Javascript alongwith Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).

I went through [Dart FAQ](https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html), but couldn't really find anything related to visualization libraries or D3.js perse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) you can use any js lib. See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) for more details.

Comment: Does Dart has some inbuilt libraries for visualization as well ? Or I will have to rely on the ones provided by Javascript only ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such package but I don't know all the packages in [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/).

Comment: I had another doubt. Will it really make sense if I use D3.js from Dart, when Dart is a kind of replacement for Javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use native ports of d3.js to make development easier since you can then write the visualization code in Dart.  A good one you should look at is [charted](https://github.com/google/charted)

Answer (score 1):

In addition I created a [package for the google visualization API](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_visualization_api).